# ubuntu 18-04 and Internet access

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a Dell PC with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Booting it up in the morning with Ubuntu,I have no Internet access. Turning it off and booting it again, this time with Windows 10, everything works fine. Now turning it off again and booting it with Ubuntu, Internet now works.
I have tried this procedure a few times and the diagnostic is the same.
Is this normal or is there a fix to get rid of the Windows 10 detour? I do not want to erase Windows 10 yet!
Is there anybody in the Community with the same problem and who can give some advice?
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I have a Dell PC with Ubuntu 18.04 and have never encountered  such a problem. Please edit your question to explain clearly how your PC accesses the internet: Wired, wifi, etc. Please edit your question to clearly explain exactly which Dell model you have. Look for patterns: Is there a consistent OS you are using before this problem occurs?

Comment: The computer is a Dell Vostro 220 type and I am using wifi wireless to access internet. My router is a Speedport w624 from the German service provider Telekom and should not be a problem as I can access internet with Windows 10.